# How to edit an existing key mapping in vim?

Tags: vim, keymapping, keymaps

How do I edit an existing mapping in vim?  I set the mapping in my .vim file using one of the standard mapping commands:

```
map ^A o]]></code>^M<GRD minus="" summary="">^M^M<p></p>^M^M</GRD>^M^M<code><![CDATA[0kkkkkk5ehi
```

I want to edit this long command to use "matlab" instead of code, e.g.:

```
map ^A o]]></matlab>^M<GRD minus="" summary="">^M^M<p></p>^M^M</GRD>^M^M<matlab><![CDATA[0kkkkkk5ehi
```

However, I don't want to edit the .vim file -- I will use the original mapping again.   I just want to change the mapping for my current session.  I tried :map ^A, but this only displays the current mapping, and I cannot copy the displayed text.

P.S. Note that the ^M and ^A characters are inserted with Ctrl-Q Ctrl-M, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tweaking a mapping for a current session only is unusual; probably that's why it's supported poorly. I would guess that you're not actually concerned about a *session*, but rather a Matlab *filetype*. For that, there's excellent support. If the `'filetype'` is detected as `matlab`, you can put a buffer-local mapping variant in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/matlab.vim`:

```
map <buffer> ^A ...
```

#### Direct editing

If you'd rather stick with your original plan, I would do it like that:

1. Open configuration: `:split ~/.vimrc`
2. Edit the mapping in-place
3. Yank the line: `yy`
4. Execute to activate for the current session: `:@"`
5. Abort the edit without saving: `:bdelete!`

#### Alternative

For a more general solution, you could also capture the output of the original `:map ^A` command via `:redir`, then `:put` that into a `:new`*scratch buffer*, and finally `:source` that. It's more manual steps and typing, but could be automated by a custom command. Worthwhile if you need this often.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up using `:redir @t` to save to a register (t) instead of a file.  Then, after running my command, I did `:redir END` followed by `"tp` to paste from the register. This got me the text I was looking for, which I successfully recreated the edited map from.

Comment: That's :redir @t <ENTER> :map ^A <ENTER>  :redir END <ENTER> "tp  to get the text used to map the ^A character.

Comment: I was able to use copy & paste to retrieve the existing mapping after typing :map ^A but that's also a bit clunky. Probably prefer the :split /etc/vim/gvimrc solution suggested here

Answer (score 0):

To set your map for the current session only, do

```
:map ^A o]]></matlab>^M<GRD minus="" summary="">^M^M<p></p>^M^M</GRD>^M^M<matlab><![CDATA[0kkkkkk5ehi
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer my question.  I was trying to get the text of an existing map; I already knew how to do this command.